# How to add a group of separate objects that remain grouped?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm using fabricjs 1.7.21 and have a button that adds text. How might I add a group of objects, such as multiple editable IText fields (see the right side) to the canvas as I can with the single IText object?

In other words, I want to be able to add things like on the right side with a click, and be able to move it around as a group.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.setHeight(500);
canvas.setWidth(500);

// Add Text
function Addtext() {
  var text = new fabric.IText("Type...", {
    fontSize: 30,
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    textAlign: "center"
  });
  canvas.add(text);
  canvas.setActiveObject(text);
  text.enterEditing();
  text.selectAll();
  text.renderCursorOrSelection(); // or canvas.renderAll();
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
}

// Right Side Objects

// Header Constants
const toppers = {
  fontSize: 27,
  hasBorders: true,
  hasControls: false,
  left: 380,
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true,
  lockRotation: true,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center",
  selectable: true,
  align: "mid",
  centeredScaling: true,
};
const headingOne = {
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center",
  selectable: true,
  align: "mid",
  fontSize: 14,
  fontStyle: "italic",
  hasBorders: true,
  hasControls: false,
  hasRotatingPoint: false,
  left: 380,
};
const headingTwo = {
  align: "mid",
  centeredScaling: true,
  fontSize: 20,
  hasBorders: true,
  hasControls: false,
  hasRotatingPoint: false,
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true,
  lockRotation: true,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center",
  selectable: true,
  left: 380,
};

canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Some Text", {
  ...toppers,
  top: 25,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Some Text", {
  ...toppers,
  fontWeight: "bold",
  top: 60,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Some Text", { 
  ...headingOne,
  top: 90,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Some Text", { 
  ...headingTwo,
  top: 110,
}));
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.21/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="Addtext()">Add Text</button>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to truly understand your need, but if all you need is a button which adds one textField to the canvas and binds it to a group, I think this should work :

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.setHeight(500);
canvas.setWidth(500);
canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
var myGroupOfText = new fabric.Group();

function Addtext() {
  var text = new fabric.IText("Type...", {
    fontSize: 30,
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    textAlign: "center"
  });
  canvas.add(text);
  myGroupOfText.add(text);      
}
```

I am not sure why you would need

```
canvas.setActiveObject(text);
text.enterEditing();
text.selectAll();
```

but if you want, I guess there is no problem to add this to your `AddText` method. Please note that 'add' method already includes a call to `canvas.renderAll()`.

Ultimately, please do not mistake `drawingMode` with an hypothetical `insertionMode`. `drawingMode` is a setting inherent to the canvas which determines whether or not free drawing (aka drawing shape by click + move) should be enable. Unless you have a very specific constraint, there is no need to re-set it each time you add an IText.

**EDIT :**
According to your comment, you might want use this :

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.setHeight(500);
canvas.setWidth(500);
canvas.isDrawingMode = false;

[...]

function addGroupOfText() {
    var myGroupOfText = new fabric.Group();
    myGroupOfText.setOptions({selectable: true});
    var options = {
        fontSize: 30,
        top: 10,
        left: 10,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        textAlign: "center",
        selectable: false,
        fontWeight: normal, // or 'bold', or a number. see docs
        underline: false, // or true
        fontStyle: normal // or 'italic'. see docs
      }
    this.addText(myGroupOfText, options); // repeat this call as many time as needed
}

function addText(group, options) {
  var text = new fabric.IText("Type...", options);
  canvas.add(text);
  group.add(text);      
}
```

This would allows you to add X textfields (by repeating X times the `addText` call) and to specify different options to each of them. I suggest you to see the docs http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html and http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html . Please note that here I set `selectable: false` to each `IText` to be sure none would be selected as one, and `selectable: true` to the group to assure it would be selectable.

If not clear, ask for precisions in comments, I'll gladly answer you.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I'm not sure if you are saying this, but I'm trying to add a group of IText fields. So for example in my code above there are the few text objects- I'd like to add those all with one click, and them be "locked together".